# Create Element with id and styles using pure JS

Tags: javascript, function, appendchild, createelement

I build a small function appending an element with an id and styles.
And know my question why does this code not work?

```
    window.addEventListener("load",function(e){
        var inButton    = document.createElement("DIV"),
            body        = document.body;
        inButton.id = "button";
        inButton.style = function (){
            height       = "200px";
            width        = "400px";
            position     = "fixed";
            top          = "50%";
            left         = "50%";
            marginLeft   = -1*(this.width / 2);
            marginTop    = -1*(this.height / 2);
        };
        body.appendChild(inButton);
    }, false);
```

I use the following html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="description"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr-.8.3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The Js Code is inside the main.js.

I checked the path again and again, but the path is totally correct.

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: `.style = function` looks weird

Comment: no, no error is outputted

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus I was a bit lazy I though it was a shortcut to don´t write inButton.style.xxx again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting `style` property correctly. Rest of code is correct.

*Here's an example*

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  var inButton = document.createElement("DIV"),
    body = document.body;
  inButton.id = "button";
  inButton.innerHTML = "Yahooooooooooooooo"; //For example

  inButton.style.height = "200px";
  inButton.style.width = "400px";
  inButton.style.position = "fixed";
  inButton.style.top = "50%";
  inButton.style.left = "50%";
  inButton.style.marginLeft = -1 * (this.width / 2);
  inButton.style.marginTop = -1 * (this.height / 2);

  body.appendChild(inButton);
}, false);
```